# Push objects to array without removing from DOM

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I have done a lot of searching but I feel like the answer could be very simple.

**What I Have:**  jQuery taking list items from a div and pushing them into an array to append into somewhere else.

**What is happening:** The objects are being pushed to the array, but they are also getting removed from the DOM.

**What I need:** To push them to the array, but also leave the originals where they were.

Here is the code I'm using for reference

```
  var leftItems = [];
  var rightItems = [];

  $('.footer-top li').slice(0,6).each(function(i) {
    leftItems.push(this);
  });

  $('.footer-top li').each(function(i) {
    rightItems.push(this);
  });

  $.each(rightItems, function(index, value) {
    $('.footer-menu-mob ul.right').append(this);
  });

  $.each(leftItems, function(index, value) {
    $('.footer-menu-mob ul.left').append(this);
  });
```

Comment: You could try `.push($(this).clone());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A given object can only be one location in the DOM at once.   So, when you `.append()` your items from the array, you're MOVING them to a new location in the DOM.  If you want a copy of those items in a new location, then you can use jQuery's `.clone()`.

See the annotations below to understand what's happening:

```
 var leftItems = [];
  var rightItems = [];

  // this makes a nice array of DOM elements, nothing is removed from
  // the DOM here
  $('.footer-top li').slice(0,6).each(function(i) {
    leftItems.push(this);
  });

  // this makes a nice array of DOM elements, nothing is removed from
  // the DOM here
  $('.footer-top li').each(function(i) {
    rightItems.push(this);
  });

  // this MOVES these elements from their current location in the DOM to
  // a new location
  $.each(rightItems, function(index, value) {
    $('.footer-menu-mob ul.right').append(this);
  });

  // this MOVES these elements from their current location in the DOM to
  // a new location
  $.each(leftItems, function(index, value) {
    $('.footer-menu-mob ul.left').append(this);
  });
```

---

If you don't need to keep the array, then you can use `.clone()` and simplify your code like this:

```
  $('.footer-top li').slice(0,6).clone().appendTo('.footer-menu-mob ul.left');
  $('.footer-top li').clone().appendTo('.footer-menu-mob ul.right');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone the DOM elements.  You can also greatly simplify your code:

```
$('.footer-top li').each(function(index, value) {
    var targetSelector = '.footer-menu-mob ul.right';
    if(index > 6) {
        targetSelector = '.footer-menu-mob ul.left';
    }   
    $(this).clone().appendTo(targetSelector);
});
```

Note that here I am assuming you want the first 7 li items to be appended to `.footer-menu-mob ul.right` and the remaining to `.footer-menu-mob ul.left`, whereas your original approach of slicing the array would have placed first seven elements in right and all elements in left. Since you re-specify the selector.